# A question regarding continuity and limits.

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

So I have a function $f$ that is continuous. Its value at $x$ different from $4$ is given by:

$$f(x)=\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x}-2}
$$

Now I have to calculate $f(4)$?

Comment: Is this $f(x)=\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x}-2}$ or $f(x)=x - \frac{4}{\sqrt{x}-2}$?

Comment: The first one, so (x-4) in the numerator

Comment: "I have a function $f$ that is continuous". No, it's not. It has a "hole" (or discontinuity) at $f(4)$. If you're question was written as $\lim_{x\to4}\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x}-2}$, that's a different problem.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: The question is fine.  It explicitly states that the formula only applies when $x$ is different from $4.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
& f(x)=\frac{x-4}{\sqrt{x}-2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x}+2}{\sqrt{x}+2}\\[8pt]
= {} &\frac{(x-4)(\sqrt{x}+2)}{x-4}=\sqrt{x}+2
\end{align}

Now you can easily evaluate at $x=4$

Answer (score 3):

$$\text{Multiplying }(\sqrt{x}+2)\text{ in both numerator and denominator}$$